# 3265:Item not found in this collection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to execute an update statement in the above code but when DoCmd.RunSQL SQL3 is executed it gives error as 3265:Item not found in this collection. Source:DAO.QueryDefs.
It would be great if someone suggests what am I missing here.

```
SQL4 = "SELECT id from tblLastID"
Set temprsGenerateBilling = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(SQL4)
bookingID = temprsGenerateBilling.Fields(0).Value + 1
SQL3 = "UPDATE tblLastID SET id=" & bookingID 
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the recordset you already have opened:

```
SQL4 = "SELECT id from tblLastID"
Set temprsGenerateBilling = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(SQL4)

If temprsGenerateBilling.RecordCount = 0 Then
    temprsGenerateBilling.AddNew
Else
    temprsGenerateBilling.Edit
End If
temprsGenerateBilling.Fields(0).Value = Nz(temprsGenerateBilling.Fields(0).Value, 0) + 1
temprsGenerateBilling.Update

temprsGenerateBilling.Close
```

Comment: Hi Gustav. Thanks for the suggestion. When I try to execute the line temprsGenerateBilling.Fields(0).Value = Nz(temprsGenerateBilling.Fields(0).Value, 0) + 1 I get the error as 3027:Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.
      Source:DAO.Field3027:Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.
      Source:DAO.Field

Comment: Well, that you will have to sort out. If the table belongs to SQL Server, there are many options.

Comment: Yes the table belongs to sql server. I'd really appreciate if you suggest a way out.

Comment: Just bing/google for _can't update table in SQL Server_. Too many options to list here.